# javascript component vaadin 23

Tags: components, vaadin

In Vaadin 23, I have a problem with this component "system notify for Vaadin v14+"

this is the error:

```
Exception is thrown during JavaScript execution. Stacktrace will be dumped separately.

The error has occurred in the JS code: '$0, $1, $2, $3, $4, window.notify.sendNotification($0, $1, $2, $3, $4)'

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendNotification') (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/@fs/C:/Users/carusom/sviluppo/workspace/xxx/xx/node_modules/.vite/deps/FlowClient-6OLYZ7QO.js?v=143fabf3:738:7)

Exception is thrown during JavaScript execution. Stacktrace will be dumped separately.

The error has occurred in the JS code: '$0, $1, $2, $3, $4, window.notify.sendNotification($0, $1, $2, $3, $4)'

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendNotification') (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/@fs/C:/Users/carusom/sviluppo/workspace/xxxxxx/xxxx/node_modules/.vite/deps/FlowClient-6OLYZ7QO.js?v=143fabf3:738:7)
```

can you help me?

thanks Massimiliano

What is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0):

What that error says is that `window.notify` doesn't exist, but the JS is written in a way that assumes it exists. To fix that, you might either make sure that the script that initializes `window.notify` is actually included or change the executed JS to gracefully deal with `window.notify` not being there.